# MongoDB/Mongoose query: How to get different sets of data based on a field's value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm using `nodejs` with [mongoose library](https://mongoosejs.com/) for my mongoDB interaction.

I'm building a landing page query (think Netflix page) and need to get ~15 results for each categories (think Comedy, Horror, Drama, ...).

It seems not like a great solution to send a query for each "category" and deal with the callback issues as well as a heavy request on the database for a simple page load...as illustrated below:

```
const categories = ['horror','drama','comedy']
let counterCallback = 0
let allShows = []
categories.map(category =>{
    Show.find({category: category},{limit: 15}, (err, shows)=>{
       if(shows){ allShows.push(shows)}
       allShows++
       if(allShows === categories.length){ return res.json(allShows) }
    })
})
```

I was thinking maybe of making an `$or` request, but I can't limit for the number for each "or"s ...

```
const categories = ['horror','drama','comedy']
Show.find({
    $or:categories.map(category=> {return {category: category} })
},{limit: 10})
```

How can I achieve a request that limits the number of results per "category"?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take advantage of MongoDB's [aggregation-framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-pipeline/) to run complex queries, try below query :

```
var categories = ['horror', 'comedy', 'drama']

Show.aggregate([
    /** This $match would help to  limit docs to particular categories, as each pipeline in facet stage has to iterate to all docs in collection for thrice as 3 categories given, So at least limiting docs to needed categories. */
    { $match: { category: { $in: categories } } }, 
    {
        $facet: {
            'horror': [{ $match: { category: 'horror' } }, { $limit: 1 }],
            'comedy': [{ $match: { category: 'comedy' } }, { $limit: 1 }],
            'drama': [{ $match: { category: 'drama' } }, { $limit: 1 }]
        }
    }])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ucje9OPy3zK)

Alternatively you can achieve that using `$group` as well :

```
Show.aggregate([
    { $match: { category: { $in: categories } } },
    { $group: { _id: '$category', shows: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $project: { category: '$_id', _id: 0, shows: { $slice: ['$shows', 1] } } },
    /** Below two stages are optional  */
    { $group: { _id: '', data: { $push: '$$ROOT' } } },
    { $project: { _id: 0 } }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/13lfLxarKy7)

Comment: Tried the first one and it works like a charm! Is there by any chance, a way to not group them (And let my frontend handle the grouping)?

Comment: @denislexic : you mean $facet ? Or $group in second query?

Comment: In $facet. So it just sends an array of `shows` instead of an object for each category.

Comment: @denislexic : It will be an array because if you've `limit >1` then each category of shows would hold multiple values, if you just want one, then you can have object for each category rather than array for each category, Try this :: https://mongoplayground.net/p/0dxeMnZqEzH

Answer (score 2):

You may use MongoDB Aggregation framework with `$group` operation.

I assume you have MongoDB v4.2. For earlier versions, instead of `{$replaceWith:"$data"}` use `{$ReplaceRoot:{newRoot:"$data"}}`

```
Show.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      category: {
        $in: [
          "horror",
          "comedy",
          "drama"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$category",
      data: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $addFields: {
      data: {
        $slice: [
          "$data",
          15
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data"
  },
  {
    $replaceWith: "$data"
  }
]).exec((err, shows) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(shows);
})
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/1hv7BqjiB8W)